# Can we Sign In yammer and get the OAuth token like "77911-1J4E7sRPVmxNpq8Cu3QA" by .Net SDK without open yammer login popup window?

Tags: yammer

Can we Sign In yammer and get the OAuth token like "77911-1J4E7sRPVmxNpq8Cu3QA" by .Net SDK without

open yammer login popup window?